# ¿como puedo hacer que el texto dentro de un textarea reduzca o aumente su tamaño antes de activarse el scroll?

Tags: javascript, angular, textarea, texto, ajustar-texto

Lo que quiero lograr es que cuando el usuario este escribiendo y llegue al final del textarea que no se active el scroll sino que el texto reduzca su tamaño y pueda seguir escribiendo y si el usuario borra texto se aumente de nuevo.

estaba intentando esto como una base, pero no logro hacer que reduzca el tamaño, no se si las propiedades que estoy usando para el calculo serían las correctas,

acá dejo lo que estaba intentando en stackblitz, estoy usando angular:

[mi intento para resolver esto](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x9dqxn?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

agradecería si me pudieran ayudar con esto.

básicamente quisiera lograr algo como la solución que da el usuario @wutzebaer en esta pregunta pero con typescript o javascript, su solución hace uso de jquery:

[pregunta similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687998/auto-size-dynamic-text-to-fill-fixed-size-container)

Disculpen, no supe como compartir el enlace para que fuese justo a la respuesta que menciono, pero pudieran hacer una busqueda con CTRL + F e ingresar `wutzebaer` y los llevara a la respuesta para que vean en el ejemplo.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar con esto. Saludos!